# lodash/underscore check if one object contains all key/values from another object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

This is probably an easy question but I haven't been able to find an answer from the lodash API docs and Google.

Let's assume I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
  code: 2,
  persistence: true
}
```

I want a function that I can pass a key/value pair and returns true if the key exists in my object and has the specified value:

```
_.XXXX(obj, {code: 2});  //true
_.XXXX(obj, {code: 3});  //false
_.XXXX(obj, {code: 2, persistence: false});  //false
_.XXXX(obj, {code: 2, persistence: true});   //true
```

This is somehow like `where()` but for only one object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a [**matcher**](http://underscorejs.org/#matcher):

```
var result1 = _.matcher({ code: 2 })( obj );  // returns true
var result2 = _.matcher({ code: 3 })( obj );  // returns false
```

with a mixin:

```
_.mixin( { keyvaluematch: function(obj, test){
    return _.matcher(test)(obj);
}});

var result1 = _.keyvaluematch(obj, { code: 2 });  // returns true
var result2 = _.keyvaluematch(obj, { code: 3 });  // returns false
```

**Edit**

Version 1.8 of underscore added an [**_.isMatch**](http://underscorejs.org/#isMatch) function.

Comment: It's important to note that [according](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.0#isMatch) to `_.isMatch`, empty array/obj. value is equal to _any and every_ array/obj. value. That might or might not be what you want. If you need more strict (and deep) comparison, see [posthtml-ast-compare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/posthtml-ast-compare).

Comment: Any reason for the down vote on the 23rd of March 2018? Anonymous downv otes don't help anyone and I would really like to know the reason so that I can correct the answer.

Answer (score 9):

https://lodash.com/docs#has

```
var obj = {
  code: 2,
  persistence: true
};

console.log(_.has(obj, 'code'));
```

My bad for misunderstanding your requirement at first.

Here's the corrected answer with `_.some` https://lodash.com/docs#some

```
var obj = {
  code: 2,
  persistence: true
};

console.log( _.some([obj], {code: 2}) );
console.log( _.some([obj], {code: 3}) );
console.log( _.some([obj], {code: 2, persistence: false}) );
console.log( _.some([obj], {code: 2, persistence: true}) );
```

The trick is to cast the object you want to check as an Array so that `_.some` will do its magic.

If you want a nicer wrapper instead of having to manually cast it with `[]`, we can write a function that wraps the casting.

```
var checkTruth = function(obj, keyValueCheck) {
  return _.some([obj], keyValueCheck);
};

console.log( checkTruth(obj, {code: 2}) );
... as above, just using the `checkTruth` function now ...
```

Comment: I want a function that I can pass a key/value pair!

Comment: My bad for misunderstanding your question. Revised with the `_.some` solution.

Comment: I like the "trick". Seems like there is such functionality under the hood. I'm wondering if there's an easier way to use it than to create a new array?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is one single underscore function for that, but you can easily write one:

```
function sameObject(ob1, ob2) {
   for (var key in ob2) {
      if (ob2[key] != ob1[key]) {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: using `for..in` loop isn't the best. Currently I'm using this function: `function containsAll(obj1, obj2) {
      return _.all(_.keys(obj2), function (key) {
          return obj1[key] === obj2[key];
      });
    }`